# jQuery input value and foreign characters

Tags: jquery, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a bilingual website

The value of a form field is set to "Correo electrónico" when the user request Spanish page.

As I try to validate form fields, if I do `alert(jQuery('input#thefield').val());`

I get: Correo electrónico

However, if I am testing the value of said input box (i.e.

```
jQuery('input#thefield').val() == "Correo electrónico"
```

)

jQuery does nto register.

TO check how jQuery was processing the string "Correo electrónico," I did an `alert("Correo electrónico");` and the output was Correo electr[a symbol look at image]nico

[image: foreign character not displayed]

What can I do to keep the field value in foreign characters, but translate this to be able to test against, as well as insert into field value if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue.

You need to check the format of your source code text file. Is it UTF-8? Or another?

Also, you should specify the encoding of your source in the HTML `<meta>` tags.

Personally, I use UTF-8 everywhere (when I can): the code source text files, the database contents, database connection, HTML, CSS, JavaScript... everything.

Comment: most files in website are UTF-8 encoded. The template displays "<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />" The processing file regarding my question, jQuery so .js extension, was not encoded. I added the UTF-8 (i.e. <script src="root/js/core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script> ) and I cut and pasted in an utf-8 encoded file but this made no difference  UPDATE: I'm sorry, it worked. I had to change the text from the jQUery file to reflect the foreign character THANK YOU